# bootstrap navbar margin-bottom doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I inspect [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) example from bootstrap, I find that the margin-bottom in navbar does not separate the navbar and the container.

Comment: Please check if the target navbar has higher z-index? As the z-index is high, the margin might be added but not pushing the content downwords. I am on mobile right no so unable to inspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the navbar is fixed positioned and when you specify some element to be positioned fixed or absolute you are removing that item from document flow hence no effect on subsequent container. Try removing position:fixed on inspect from nav and you will see margin bottom in effect.